# SQL Trigger that will prevent an UPDATE if Order QTY is Greater than Units in Stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Create an UPDATE trigger called tr_check_qty on the OrderDetails table to prevent the updating of
the quantity in the OrderDetails table if the quantity amount is greater than the units in stock in the
Products table. Use the following queries to test your trigger.

```
UPDATE OrderDetails (The trigger should prevent the update.)

SET Quantity = 5
WHERE OrderID = 10008
AND ProductID = 21

UPDATE OrderDetails (The trigger should allow the update.)
SET Quantity = 10
WHERE OrderID = 10008
AND ProductID = 14
```

I am not so familiar with triggers, but I have started my code as follow...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_qty
ON OrdersDetails
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF  ( SELECT
         od.Quantity
         ,p.UnitsInStock
       FROM
         OrderDetails od
         INNER JOIN Products p
         ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
       WHERE
         od.Quantity . p.UnitsInStock 
    )

BEGIN
RAISERROR ('The Quantity Amount is greater than the units in the Product available!', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RETURN 
END
```

So i get my ERROR but I can not make this Validate. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Validate"?  What is not validating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a homework problem, so I'm not going to give you a complete solution. But, as a hint, take a look at an Instead Of trigger. [Click for an example.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this did lead me to the answer I was looking for.